# Падает mysql при запуске системы

Tags: mysql, sql, debian, systemd

День добрый. Имеем сервачок на debian, а именно Linux "hostname" 5.4.0-kali3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.4.13-1kali1 (2020-01-20) x86_64 GNU/Linux
Стоит apache2 + php, и много чего ещё. Также почтовый сервер. Ну вообщем, при запуске сервера крашется Mysql: Ввожу systemctl status

```
● "hosthame"
    State: degraded``
     Jobs: 0 queued
   Failed: 1 units
    Since: Mon 2020-02-24 19:49:36 +07; 33min ago
   CGroup: /
           ├─user.slice
           │ ├─user-132.slice
           │ │ ├─user@132.service …
           │ │ │ ├─gsd-xsettings.service
           │ │ │ │ └─2242 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-xsettings
           │ │ │ ├─gsd-power.service
           │ │ │ │ └─2231 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-power
           │ │ │ ├─xdg-permission-store.service
           │ │ │ │ └─2179 /usr/libexec/xdg-permission-store
           │ │ │ ├─gsd-sound.service
           │ │ │ │ └─2239 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-sound
           │ │ │ ├─gsd-rfkill.service
           │ │ │ │ └─2236 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-rfkill
           │ │ │ ├─gsd-print-notifications.service
           │ │ │ │ ├─2232 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-print-notifications
           │ │ │ │ └─2273 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-printer
           │ │ │ ├─gsd-a11y-settings.service
lines 1-23
```

systemctl status mysql При вводе этого -

```
root@"hostname":~# systemctl status mysql
● mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql; generated)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-02-24 20:28:16 +07; 8min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Process: 704 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

фев 24 20:28:26 "hostname" mysqld[1161]: 2020-02-24 20:28:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
фев 24 20:28:26 "hostname" mysqld[1161]: 2020-02-24 20:28:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.22 started; log sequence number 5751028; transaction id 13877
фев 24 20:28:26 "hostname" mysqld[1161]: 2020-02-24 20:28:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
фев 24 20:28:26 "hostname" mysqld[1161]: 2020-02-24 20:28:26 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
фев 24 20:28:27 "hostname" mysqld[1161]: 2020-02-24 20:28:27 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
фев 24 20:28:31 "hostname" mysqld[1161]: 2020-02-24 20:28:31 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
фев 24 20:28:31 "hostname" mysqld[1161]: 2020-02-24 20:28:31 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
фев 24 20:28:31 "hostname" mysqld[1161]: 2020-02-24 20:28:31 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
фев 24 20:28:31 "hostname" mysqld[1161]: Version: '10.3.22-MariaDB-1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  Debian buildd-unstable
фев 24 20:28:43 "hostname" mysqld[1161]: 2020-02-24 20:28:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200224 20:28:43
```

Самое интересное, что обращаться к mysql можно до сих пор, и при перезапуске самого sql командой systemctl restart, сразу по понормальному всё запускается, без failed. Как то это надо исправить.

Comment: Вам уже ниже ответили, но все же. Вот смотрите: в логах нет ничего, что говорит о том, что сервер рухнул. Да и отвечает от на запросы. Поэтому нужно искать проблему не в демоне, а в инструменте, который сообщил об этой проблеме. Также `ps aux | grep mysql` даст ответ - запущен или нет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MYSQLD_STARTUP_TIMEOUT по умолчанию 30 секунд. Возможно просто стартовый скрипт не дожидается запуска сервера. Реиндекс какой-нибудь или восстановление по сбою...

Переходи на запуск с Системд:

```
systemctl disable mysql
systemctl enable mariadb
```

Там и лог подробнее увидишь и аналитику по запуску можно сделать.

Comment: Помогло. Спасибо огромное.